# In React, would like "react-scripts start" to show eslint warnings

Tags: create-react-app

Within my create-react-app build, if I run "eslint src/**/*.js", it happily shows me both the eslint warnings and errors.  When I run "react start", it only shows me the eslint errors, and not the warnings.   I'd like to see both the errors and warnings on "react start".   Any obvious way to configure that ?

Comment: I believe that's implemented by https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin and CRA doesn't expose the Webpack config. I'd recommend not having *any* ESLint warnings; don't make people read through and figure out which things they *actually* need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have this in your package.json?

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ]
}
```